# Formatting issue for mobile responsive github page using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Wondering how to fix the mobile version of my [github page](http://chloewatson.github.io), which I made tweaking a bootstrap template. On the mobile version only, the navbar cuts off the top of the first image in my portfolio. I can't figure out how to fix it, I think the problem is in the navbar:

```
     <!-- navbar-->
<header class="header">
  <div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll"><a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">CHLOE WATSON COLLAGE</a>
        <div class="navbar-buttons">
          <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle navbar-btn ">Menu<i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="page-scroll"> 
              <a href="#portfolio">WORKS</a>
          </li>
          <li class = "page-scroll"> 
              <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-scroll">
              <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks! I've also linked to my repository if the above code is not enough.

https://github.com/chloewatson/chloewatson.github.io/blob/master/index.html

Comment: You need the same layout? means the header.

Comment: Hi Lijin, same layout preferred but if you have a fix that involves something different that's OK @LIJINSAMUEL  what do you mean about the header?

Comment: give padding top same height as header to #portfolio using media queruies.

Answer (score 0):

fist thing you brand name **CHLOE WATSON COLLAGE** so long for mobile device remove   `letter spacing` in mobile

```
@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:767px) {
.navbar a.navbar-brand {
             letter-spacing: 0;
            }
}
```

i thing it's ok but if these not working then  use second css add your css file in last line

```
    @media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:767px) {
        #portfolio {
            padding-top: 121px;
        }
       .navbar a.navbar-brand {
         letter-spacing: 0;
        }
    }
```